# asp.net webforms : go to previous page using back browser button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on an ASP.NET Web Forms solution having several pages that are accessible using a navigation bar. I have notice that, after having edited some fields with AutoPostback enabled, pressing the browser's BACK button will show the previous state of the current page instead of showing the previous page.

The solutions I found to this issue suggest using Redirect() in a button's click event handler or using some Javascript to detect a BACK button click then call window.history.back(). The first type of solution is not acceptable to me because I don't want to have in my UI a dedicated button for backward navigation. The second solution did not work for me.

So, for a Web Forms application, what is the right approach to make the browser's BACK button showing the previous page?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Difficult to help without code, but you could store the URL of the last full page you want to revert to, and then instead of using window.history.back(), you redirect to the stored URL.

Comment: That's pretty much how the web work, each post back is a new page. You could try using ajax, which can load just a specific part of the page instead of loading a new page.

Comment: When you say that second method failed, how exactly did it fail?